# Why am I getting an undefined index error in my algorithm for in place quicksort?

Tags: php, algorithm

```
<?php

$arr = array('1', '-1', '3', '-2');

function inPlaceQuicksort($arr){
    inPlaceQuickSortProcessing($arr, 0, count($arr));
    return $arr;
}

function inPlaceQuickSortProcessing(&$arr, $pivotIndex, $arraySize){

    if($pivotIndex + 1>= $arraySize)
        return;
    else{
        for($i = $pivotIndex + 1; $i++; $i<$arraySize){

            if($arr[$i] < $arr[$pivotIndex]){
                $temp = $arr[$i];
                unset($arr[$i]);
                array_values($arr);
                array_splice($arr, $pivotIndex, 0, $temp);
                $pivotIndex++;
            }
        }                
    }
    //inPlaceQuickSortProcessing($arr, 0, $pivotIndex+1);
    //inPlaceQuickSortProcessing($arr, $pivotIndex+1, $arraySize);            
}

inPlaceQuicksort($arr);


?>
```

Doesn't the last expression in the for loop make sure `$i<$arraySize`?

Comment: Why don't you print out the variable values to find out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for($i = $pivotIndex + 1; $i++; $i<$arraySize){
```

should be

```
for($i = $pivotIndex + 1; $i<$arraySize; $i++){
```